# How do I write this address of a function from C++ to C#?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, directx, c++-cx

I'm learning DirectX but I don't know C++ very well so I decided to use SharpDX instead.  But I'm stuck on this part in C++ they use the address of a function in the TypedEventHandler, but I don't know how to write that in C#?  Can anyone help?

```
ref class App sealed : public IFrameworkView
{
public:
virtual void Initialize(CoreApplicationView^ AppView)
{
    AppView->Activated += ref new TypedEventHandler
        <CoreApplicationView^, IActivatedEventArgs^>(this, &App::OnActivated);
}
virtual void SetWindow(CoreWindow^ Window) {}
virtual void Load(String^ EntryPoint) {}
virtual void Run() {}
virtual void Uninitialize() {}

void OnActivated(CoreApplicationView^ CoreAppView, IActivatedEventArgs^ Args)
{
    CoreWindow^ Window = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();
    Window->Activate();
}
};
```

My conversion so far

```
internal class App : IFrameworkView
{
    public void Initialize(CoreApplicationView AppView)
    {
        // Call OnActivated() when the Activated event is triggered
        AppView.Activated += new TypedEventHandler<CoreApplicationView, IActivatedEventArgs>(this,this.OnActivated);

    }
    public void SetWindow(CoreWindow Window) {}
    public void Load(String EntryPoint) {}
    public void Run() {}
    public void Uninitialize() {}

    public void OnActivated(CoreApplicationView CoreAppView, IActivatedEventArgs Args)
    {
        CoreWindow Window = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread();
        Window.Activate();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where did you find `ref new`?  That's not legal.  The rest of your code is C++/CLI, not standard C++.  C++/CLI should be very straightforward to translate into C#.

Comment: @KenKin: No, C++/CLI uses `gcnew`.  Is this `C++/CX`?

Comment: Yeah it is.  Fixing tags.

Comment: its C++/CX for Windows Store apps

Comment: @erotavlas: It would be better to state that in the question, but now it's retagged finely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the "this" argument for the C# event wireup:

```
public sealed class App : IFrameworkView
{
    public virtual void Initialize(CoreApplicationView AppView)
    {
        AppView.Activated += new TypedEventHandler <CoreApplicationView, IActivatedEventArgs>(OnActivated);
    }

    public virtual void SetWindow(CoreWindow Window)
    {
    }
    public virtual void Load(string EntryPoint)
    {
    }
    public virtual void Run()
    {
    }
    public virtual void Uninitialize()
    {
    }

    public void OnActivated(CoreApplicationView CoreAppView, IActivatedEventArgs Args)
    {
        CoreWindow Window = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread();
        Window.Activate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be able to shorten that to `AppView.Activated += OnActivated;`

Comment: Absolutely (although that won't work in older versions of C#).